# Teradata DATEDIFF Error

Tags: teradata, datediff

Hi i am getting an error as expected something like END keyword between DATEDIFF and (
for the below statement under

```
select
   case when CC.CASE_STS_CD in ( 'Closed', 'Auto Closed') then
        DATEDIFF(second,CC.REC_DTTM_PST,CC.CRT_DTTM_PST) end as CASE_RES_DUR_IN_SECS,
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your fields are DATE datatype (otherwise you'll need to cast):

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN
    CC.CASE_STS_CD IN ('Closed','Auto Closed') THEN
    (CC.REC_DTTM_PST - CC.CRT_DTTM_PST) * 86400
END AS CASE_RES_DUR_IN_SECS
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no `DATEDIFF` function in Teradata.

This is a generic SQL UDF I wrote a few years ago for calculating the difference of two timestamps in seconds:

```
REPLACE FUNCTION TimeStamp_Diff_Seconds
(
   ts1 TIMESTAMP(6)
  ,ts2 TIMESTAMP(6)
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(18,6)
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COLLATION INVOKER
INLINE TYPE 1
RETURN
(CAST((CAST(ts2 AS DATE)- CAST(ts1 AS DATE)) AS DECIMAL(18,6)) * 60*60*24)
      + ((EXTRACT(  HOUR FROM ts2) - EXTRACT(  HOUR FROM ts1)) * 60*60)
      + ((EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts2) - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts1)) * 60)
      +  (EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts2) - EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts1))
;
```