# Oracle syntax Vs teradata Syntax

Tags: teradata

Let's say I have 2 columns Start date and end date both are timestamp.

I want to subtract both (Start date - end date ) as date diff

But it's throwing me error. What should be the correct syntax.

Note:- I am doing this in teradata

Comment: What do you actually have in your query? And what error are you getting?

Comment: Well I got a query which was in Oracle SQL format ...I need the same to be converted into teradata...both the column in teradata are in timestamp...I am getting some thing like Invalid  Datetime and interval error

Comment: You'll need to post some sample data and the query you're using (at least the date calculation).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33792549/2527905 for calculating the difference in seconds (intervals will overflow when it's more than 9999 day). To get the same result as Oracle you can divide the result by 86400

Comment: @VinayakDas https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
select Current_date, (Current_date-1);

select cast(Current_Timestamp as date), (cast(Current_Timestamp as date)-1);
```

Comment: The OP asked for the *difference*  between two timestamps, not how to subtract a day from a date/timestamp.

Comment: Second line reflects this.

Comment: There's no difference in the 2nd line, it's a date minus one day.